Indexing strategy for a very read-heavy application with most business logic managed by the database
We're working on migrating from a NoSQL database to Postgres. Our entire business logic (complex network calculations) is handled by the database – we have approx. 150 tables, 300+ dynamic views (generated by queries), 300+ queries joining 4-12 tables with complex JOINs, lots of JSONB columns, etc.
The application is very read-heavy – writes to the database happen very rarely (once every several days) and in one huge batch, and is not particularly time-constrained.
I want to ask for a general advice on how to approach indexing & data model normalization / optimization for such an application. Do we just create an index for every single (or most) join condition in each query, with (possibly) lots of overlaps? Create a materialized view for each query result? Etc.

No, you can only design indexes together with the queries. Not every join strategy benefits from indexes.
